# How to blur current view on click event of button and set images on that blurred view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

I want to make something like

[image: this].

I have tried render script to achieve this. Though I'm unable to achieve this.
I want this blur effect over background view by clicking the edit button.
please help me.

Comment: use this https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

Answer (score 0):

look at here!  https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment

Add gradle dependency

```
compile 'fr.tvbarthel.blurdialogfragment:lib:2.2.0'
```

create your own dialog

```
public class SampleDialogFragment extends MyCustomDialogFragment {

     /**
     * Engine used to blur.
     */
    private BlurDialogEngine mBlurEngine;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBlurEngine = new BlurDialogEngine(getActivity());
        mBlurEngine.setBlurRadius(8);
        mBlurEngine.setDownScaleFactor(8f);
        mBlurEngine.debug(true);
        mBlurEngine.setBlurActionBar(true);
        mBlurEngine.setUseRenderScript(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mBlurEngine.onResume(getRetainInstance());
    }

     @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        mBlurEngine.onDismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mBlurEngine.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null) {
            getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    ...
}
```